# Unity: "Unable to Read Header from Archive File"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've inherited a project, and after compiling/building/running in Unity editor, I'm seeing this error:

"Unable to read header from archive file:

What issues might contribute to this?  The prefabs, themselves, seem valid from within the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The AssetBundle path is probably wrong now.

[Asset Bundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html)

Comment: I've verified the path by modifying the file name in the directory.  The error message if it doesn't actually find the file isn't "Unable to read header," but more like "Unable to find/locate archive."  So, I know the directory is correct...